# Oracle Procedure Log Events

Tags: oracle, procedure

Bellow is my procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CUSTOMER_INCREMENTAL" (
   IS   
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO PROC_LOG (START_DATE,OUTPUT) VALUES (sysdate,Process Started);

  INSERT INTO NDB_AML_CUSTOMER 
   (ID, TITLE,...)
  SELECT ID, TITLE,... 
   FROM NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW
   WHERE DATE_TIME > (SELECT RUN_DATE FROM CHECK_POINT WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW');

  UPDATE CHECK_POINT SET RUN_DATE = SYSDATE WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW';

  COMMIT; 

    INSERT INTO PROC_LOG (END_DATE,OUTPUT) VALUES (sysdate,Process Ended);

END;
/
```

I want to output log events into a table. Such as, the start date & time of the procedure with the even called "Process started", and Process End date & time and during an exception the error message. So three columns in the Log_table, Start Date, End Date & Output. Looking for input from experts.

Comment: Logging procedures usually use `pragma autonomous transaction` to make sure they do not get rolled back when the whole transaction has to be rolled back; and they do not commit the whole transaction either. Otherwise, what exactly is your question?!?

Comment: I want to handle events in the procedure, like when the procedure started to execute, when it ended and in an exception the error message. No roll-back is needed because in an exception like the source table name changed then the procedure won't select records at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can catch exceptions in procedures as mentioned in this article [Exception handling](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/when_others.php). For your logging of the start and end date you can use a simple insert statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CUSTOMER_INCREMENTAL" (
   IS   
BEGIN

  Process start event

INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, MESSAGE) VALUES (ID, SYSDATE, NULL, NULL);

  INSERT INTO NDB_AML_CUSTOMER 
   (ID, TITLE,...)
  SELECT ID, TITLE,... 
   FROM NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW
   WHERE DATE_TIME > (SELECT RUN_DATE FROM CHECK_POINT WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW');

  UPDATE CHECK_POINT SET RUN_DATE = SYSDATE WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW';

  COMMIT;
  UPDATE LOG_TABLE SET END_DATE = SYSDATE WHERE ID = ID;
  Process End event

EXCEPTION

WHEN OTHERS THEN
UPDATE LOG_TABLE SET END_DATE = SYSDATE, MESSAGE = EXCEPTION_MESSAGE WHERE ID = ID;

END;
```

Some thing like this snippet

Comment: In UPDATE statements, ID=ID means?

Comment: The naming was a little bit confusing sorry. The first ID is the field and the second one the value.  You need a unique identifier to get a proper update statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have a separate process logging package that outputs messages to my log table (using `pragma autonomous transaction`), as well as using dbms_application_info so that you can see what a session is doing when querying v$session.

I then have wrapper procedures in my actual code packages that pass in package info, log message type (info, error, etc.).

I would highly recommend you look at https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/instrumenting-your-plsql-code, as Tim has examples of his logging packages available for you to look through.